# Most pythonic way to write a function to either pass in arguments or a tuple of arguments

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

What is a most pythonic way to write a function to either pass in arguments or a tuple/list of arguments?

For example, a function `add` could either take in an argument of `add(1, 2)` or `add((1, 2))` and both output `3`.

What I have so far: (it works, but does not look nice)

```
def add(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return (args[0][0] + args[0][1])
    if len(args) == 2:
        return args[0] + args[1]
    else:
        print "error: add takes in one or two arguments"
```

What I don't like about it is:

1. I have to print the error about passing in one or two arguments
2. The `args[0][0]` looks very unreadable
3. This way, it is hard to tell what the arguments passed in represent (they don't have names)

Comment: Generally, I would not recommend writing such versatile functions. I still do it myself, but it gets me into trouble sometimes. You should just be prepared to structure the rest of your code in a way that complies with a function that takes a tuple/list of two numbers or with a function that takes two arguments. This will force the rest of your code to be standardized and therefore easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function takes a specific number of arguments, then the most pythonic way to do this is to **not** do it. Rather if the user has a tuple with the arguments, you make them unpack them when they call the function. E.g.

```
def add(a, b):
   return a + b
```

Then the caller can do

```
add(1,2)
```

or

```
t = (1,2)
add(*t)
```

The only time you want to accept either a sequence of params or individual params is when you can have any arbitrary (non-zero) number of arguments (e.g. the `max` and `min` builtin functions) in which case you'd just use `*args`

Answer (score 5):

I dont know if this is the most "pythonic" way but it will do what you want:

```
def add(a, b=None):
    return a+b if b is not None else sum(a)
```

Comment: I think you meant `is not` there, rather than `=` (which is a syntax error).

Answer (score 1):

If you can only take a finite number of arguments, it makes more sense to ask for those specifically.  If you can accept an arbitrary number of arguments, then the `*args` paradigm works well if you loop through it.  Mixing and matching those two aren't very elegant.

```
def add(*args):
    total = 0
    for i in args:
        total += i
    return total

>>> add(1, 2, 3)
6
```

(I know we could just use `sum()` there, but I'm trying to make it look a bit more general)

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of python duck typing, if you see 1 argument, assume its something that expands to 2 arguments. If its then 2, assume its two things that add together. If it violates your rules, raise an exception like python would do on a function call.

```
def add(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        args = args[0]
    if len(args) != 2:
        raise TypeError("add takes 2 arguments or a tuple of 2 arguments")
    return args[0] + args[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A decorator would be best suited for this job.

```
from functools import wraps

def tupled_arguments(f):
    @wraps(f)  # keeps name, docstring etc. of f
    def accepts_tuple(tup, *args):
        if not args:  # only one argument given
            return f(*tup)
        return f(tup, *args)
    return accepts_tuple

@tupled_arguments
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```